# python2.7 __str__ cause UnicodeEncodeError when print

Tags: python

I tried to rewrite my class's **str** method, this is my code:

```
# encoding: utf8
import json


class Test(object):

    def __str__(self):
        d = {
            'foo': u'中文'
        }

        return json.dumps(d, ensure_ascii=False)


test = Test()
print test.__str__()
print test
```

what make me confused is that `print test.__str__()` works fine, but `print test` cause exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(test)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 9-10: ordinal not in range(128)
python test.py  0.05s user 0.03s system 96% cpu 0.078 total
```

python version 2.7.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__str__` **must** return a string value. If you return a `unicode` object instead, it'll be automatically encoded as ASCII.

Encode explicitly instead:

```
class Test(object):
    def __str__(self):
        d = {
            'foo': u'中文'
        }
        return json.dumps(d, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')
```

Personally, I'd not use the `__str__` method to provide a JSON encoding. Pick a different method name instead, like `tojson()`.